# Pyspark dataframe how to drop rows with nulls in all columns?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

For a dataframe, before it is like:

```
+----+----+----+
|  ID|TYPE|CODE|
+----+----+----+
|   1|   B|  X1|
|null|null|null|
|null|   B|  X1|
+----+----+----+
```

After I hope it's like:

```
+----+----+----+
|  ID|TYPE|CODE|
+----+----+----+
|   1|   B|  X1|
|null|   B|  X1|
+----+----+----+
```

I prefer a general method such that it can apply when `df.columns` is very long.
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to use `functools.reduce` to construct the conditions:

```py
from functools import reduce
df.filter(~reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, [df[c].isNull() for c in df.columns])).show()
+----+----+----+
|  ID|TYPE|CODE|
+----+----+----+
|   1|   B|  X1|
|null|   B|  X1|
+----+----+----+
```

where `reduce` produce a query as follows:

```py
~reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, [df[c].isNull() for c in df.columns])
# Column<b'(NOT (((ID IS NULL) AND (TYPE IS NULL)) AND (CODE IS NULL)))'>
```

Answer (score 21):

Providing strategy for `na.drop` is all you need:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, "B", "X1"), (None, None, None), (None, "B", "X1"), (None, "C", None)],
    ("ID", "TYPE", "CODE")
)

df.na.drop(how="all").show()
```

```
+----+----+----+
|  ID|TYPE|CODE|
+----+----+----+  
|   1|   B|  X1|
|null|   B|  X1|
|null|   C|null|
+----+----+----+
```

Alternative formulation can be achieved with `threshold` (number of `NOT NULL` values):

```
df.na.drop(thresh=1).show()
```

```
+----+----+----+
|  ID|TYPE|CODE|
+----+----+----+
|   1|   B|  X1|
|null|   B|  X1|
|null|   C|null|
+----+----+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
df=df.dropna(how='all')
```