# Python / Pyspark - Count NULL, empty and NaN

Tags: python, pyspark

i want to count NULL, empty and NaN values in a column.
I tried it like this:

```
df.filter( (df["ID"] == "") | (df["ID"].isNull()) | ( df["ID"].isnan()) ).count()
```

But i always get this error message:

```
TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

Does anyone have an idea what might be the problem?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`isnan` is not a method belonging to the `Column` class, you need to import it:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import isnan
```

And use it like:

```
df.filter((df["ID"] == "") | df["ID"].isNull() | isnan(df["ID"])).count()
```

Comment: Do you have an ideao how i can check multiple columns in this query? df["Col1, Col2, Col3"] == ""

Comment: One possibility is to use `functools.reduce`, see the answer I made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48228909/pyspark-dataframe-how-to-drop-rows-with-nulls-in-all-columns/48229211#48229211).